# ¿Cómo insertar datos en una base de datos mediante ajax-jquey en ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net, mvc

Tengo tres días tratando de concretar este código, ¿alguién me puede decir qué estoy haciendo mal?:

**Controller**:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Empleado empleado)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _db.Empleados.Add(empleado);
        _db.SaveChanges();

        return Json(empleado);
    }

    return Json(null);
}
```

**Model**:

```
public class Empleado
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
}
```

**View**:

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.Empleado

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<form id="formulario">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Nombre, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Nombre" })
        <input type="submit" value="Confirmar" class="btn btn-success" id="btnConfirmar" />
    </div>
</form>

<div id="resultado"></div>
@section Scripts{
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#btnConfirmar').click(function () {
                    var data = $('#formulario').serialize();
                    var url = "@Url.Action("Index", "Home")";

                    $.post(url, data).done(function () {
                        $('#resultado').html("Guardado");
                    })
                    .fail(function () {
                        $('#resultado').html("Error");
                    });
                });
            });

        </script>
}
```

Cabe resaltar que también lo intenté con el metodo `$.ajax({})` pero tampoco me funcionó.

Comment: Me parece son varias cosas inherentes a lo que te ocurre, te sugiero "Introducción a ASP.NET MVC" en Microsoft Virtual Academy; a mi me sirvio de mucho; entre muchas cosas es que reemplazaste el *Html.BeginForm* por el *<form>* en MVC no hay que hacer ciertos cambios. Éxitos

Comment: Hola siempre uso el Html.BeginForm pero en los tutoriales que he visto con ajax no lo han usado y tampoco me funcionó

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te recomiendo esta vía:

1- Instala el paquete nuget (microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax)

```
Install-Package microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax
```

En tu vista index: Views/Empleado/Index.cshtml

```
@model myapp.Models.Empleado

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<ul id="resultado">
@foreach (var empleado in ViewBag.Empleados)
{
    <li>@empleado.Nombre</li>
}
</ul>
<h2>Nuevo empleado</h2>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Empleado", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "resultado", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()


<div class="form-horizontal">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nombre, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nombre)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nombre)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Crear" class="btn btn-success" />
    </div>
</div>
}

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
}
```

En tu controller: EmpleadoController.cs:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Empleados = db.Empleadoes.ToList();
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="Nombre")] Empleado empleado)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Empleadoes.Add(empleado);
            db.SaveChanges();
            ViewBag.Empleados = db.Empleadoes.ToList();
            return PartialView("_EmpleadosPartial");
        }

        return View(empleado);
    }
```

Y en la vista parcial: Views/Empleado/_EmpleadosPartial.cshtml:

```
@model myapp.Models.Empleado

@foreach (var empleado in ViewBag.Empleados)
{
    <li>@empleado.Nombre</li>
}
```

¿Cómo funciona esto? De la siguiente manera:

Con:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Empleado", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "resultado", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
```

Estas especificando un formulario que usa Ajax, el cual está llamado la acción `Create` del controlador `Empleado` con método `POST` cuyo resultado será renderizado en la etiqueta cuyo Id sea `resultado`, por eso estoy llamando una vista parcial en mi controlador. Eso es todo espero te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Justamente es lo que estaba haciendo uno muy parecido, la verdad que muchas gracias por haberte tomado el tiempo de ayudarme, bendiciones!

Comment: Hola practicamente copié tu codigo pero con otro modelo llamado persona a la cual le agregé la propiedad Edad, el codigo me inserta pero hace un reload de la página estoy empezando a creer que el error no está en el codigo

Comment: Eso puede ser porque jquery.unobtrusive no esta trabajando.Pero de ser así lo que pasa es que te carga la parcial sola. Prueba hacer la referencia del script en el head de tu layout o verifica que tienes bien declarado el @section scripts. Otra cosa puede ser que no creaste la parcial como se debe. En Views/Home crea tu vista y asegurate de que no hereda de layout osea en el formulario para crear la vista solo esté marcada la pleca "create as a partial view"

Comment: Si amigo, ya me funciona no sé como pero sin ningún cambio me funcionó ya estaba que me jalaba el cabello, gracias!!

Comment: Pero ahí no se podría evaluar el tipo de retorno que viene desde el meotodo del controlador, me refiero cuando se usaba retorno tipo Json en el metodo del controller, en la vista no se podrá obtener ese valor para mostrar algun mensaje de alerta diciendo éxito de la operación??algo como OnSuccess ???

Answer (score 0):

Aquí la actualización

modelo

```
       public class Persona
       {
       [Key]
       public int Id { get; set; }

       [Required]
       public string Nombre { get; set; }

       [Required]
       public int Edad { get; set; }
       }
```

controlador home

```
           private Context _db = new Context();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Personas = _db.Personas.ToList();
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Nombre, Edad")] Persona persona)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.Personas.Add(persona);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            ViewBag.Personas = _db.Personas.ToList();
            return PartialView("_PersonasPartial");
        }

        return View(persona);
    }
```

Vista Index

```
      @model Ajax.Models.Persona


       @{
       ViewBag.Title = "Index";
        }

        <ul id="resultado">
        @foreach (var persona in ViewBag.Personas)
        {
        <li>@persona.Nombre</li>
         <li>@persona.Edad</li>
        }
      </ul>



          <h2>Nueva persona</h2>


          @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Home", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "resultado", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
          {
          @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


          <div class="form-horizontal">
         @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nombre, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nombre)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nombre)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Edad, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Edad)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Edad)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Crear" class="btn btn-success" />
    </div>
    </div>
     }

     @section Scripts {
      @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
      <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
      }
```

vista parcial

```
          @model Ajax.Models.Persona

         @foreach (var persona in ViewBag.Personas)
           {
        <li>@persona.Nombre</li>
         <li>@persona.Edad</li>
        }
```